# Attribute selector doesnt work

Tags: image, css, css-selectors, selector

Im trying to select img tags based on the alt attribute to load proper background-image on mobile

the problem is not matter what combination of attribute selector I use it seems it doesnt work, I cant even select the tag I want with it

I used these

```
img[alt="Chelo Kebab"] {opacity: 0.5}
img[alt*="Chelo Kebab"] {opacity: 0.5}
img[alt^="Chelo Kebab"] {opacity: 0.5}
```

i used all combinations, capital, normal even I tried

```
img[alt] {opacity: 0.5}
```

but no success
also I tried to put parent class name before img

you can see the code Im working on in this address
[here](http://www.test.doublelift.kr/#menu)

Im trying to select each img tag

here is the proof that I write everything correct 
[image]

**UPDATE Its obvious now its a CACHeING problem, Im trying to solve**

Comment: Where is the selector part in your code? Add a sample/basic example, not a link to a working website.

Comment: the link is working

Comment: I never said the link doesn't work...

Comment: And your selector is working, too, as f.e. simply entering `$$('img[alt="Chelo Kebab"]')` in Chrome console proves. So now you still owe us an actual problem description.

Comment: I completely understand what you saying but the problem is Im figuring out why on this webste it doesnt work

Comment: And adding a new rule with selector `img[alt="Chelo Kebab"]` via dev tools also works ...

Comment: I see you `img[alt="Chelo Kebab"]` rule in dev tools, and when I add f.e. `border: 5px solid red` to the style declaration for that rule, the effect also shows immediately ...

Comment: Your selectors look good.. maybe your style is overwritten by `img[alt] {opacity: 0.5;}`

Comment: I double checked again , I write everything correctly, I can give you screen shots , but It doesnt work, I put it at the end of my stylesheet file even with !important rule

Comment: If its overwritten why it doesnt show up in chrome dev tool

Comment: It is not overwritten, it shows up fine, and even the computed styles show `opacity: 0.5` for the images in question.

Comment: And if I set `opacity: 1` for only one of those images directly, the difference to the other images becomes apparent immediately, too.

Comment: @CameronA check the update in my answer regarding the general `img[alt]` selector in your code

Comment: _“here is the proof that I write everything correct”_ - we don’t need that at this moment, we first of all need proof that any problem actually exists. No one here seems to be able to reproduce the problem you are talking about under the link you have given.

Comment: let me trying out again, will be back soon

Comment: GUYS ITS A CACHE PROBLEM , the behavior is so RANDOM, Im trying to figuring out whats going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with attribute-selectors for iamges in css:

```css
img[alt="abc"] {
  opacity: 0.8 !important;
}
img[alt="def"] {
  opacity: 0.5 !important;
}
img[alt="ghi"] {
  opacity: 0.3 !important;
}
img[alt] {
  opacity: 0.1;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff" /><br />
<img alt="abc" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff" /><br />
<img alt="def" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff" /><br />
<img alt="ghi" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff" /><br />
```

> Note that because you have a more general selector in your code (`img[alt]`) I added the `!important` to the properties to override the opacity in your general selector.

Comment: Im trying to figuring out, because when I add something like this div.someClass img[alt="Chelo Kebab"]  it doesnt work , When I add !important also it doenst work ... fraustrated

Comment: maybe your `img` is **not** inside your `div.someClass` in your DOM

Comment: i modifier would be a nice touch with alt but no support in IE/Edge alas ([demo](https://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/brRPvy) as a pen | [support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors$edit#Browser_compatibility) on MDN)

Comment: I changed the rule to border: 10px solid blue and It worked! interesting but opacity: 0.5 doesnt work , why? its odd,

Comment: Its a cache problem, randomly it works or not , I try to refresh with ctrl+f5 everytime, but the behavior is random